# TSQL, check if comman has space after it for string

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a string I need to feed into function /it's all about aka alphabethizing names in format  `Dow, John W`  with exact casing.  In my case I need to space after comma for my function, and some strings don't have them, how to do it in most effective way? I tried to do something like below with range [] but it doesn't work.
Basically I want logic: if not space after comma, then insert space, I don't want to touch function itself, as it's legacy stuff.

```
DECLARE @inpstring VARCHAR(100) = 'DOW,JohN   W'
SELECT  Replace(@inpstring,'[A-Z],[A-Z]','[A-Z], [A-Z]')
-- s'be 'Dow, John   W'
```

Tx
M

Comment: Are you only ever expecting to see the one comma? Or, should this rule about the space only apply to the first comma?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming there is only one `,` in string you can use:

```
DECLARE @inpstring VARCHAR(100) = 'DOW,JohN   W'
SELECT CASE 
        WHEN PATINDEX('%,[A-Z]%', @inpstring) > 0 THEN Replace(@inpstring,',',', ')
        ELSE @inpstring
       END
```

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/377940)**</kbd>

And for multiple commas:

```
DECLARE @inpstring VARCHAR(100) = 'A,B,C, D'
SELECT @inpstring = 
    CASE 
      WHEN PATINDEX('%,[A-Z]%', @inpstring) > 0 
      THEN REPLACE(Replace(@inpstring,',',', '), ',  ', ', ')
      ELSE @inpstring
    END

PRINT(@inpstring);
```

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo2`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/377943)**</kbd>